# Angular 2 Upgrade to RC 1

Tags: angular

I'm in the process of upgrading from Angular 2 beta.12 to RC 1. I'm using a combination of `@angular/router` and `@angular/router-deprecated` to get started. My app compiles fine, but when I try to open it in the browser, I get an error. Here's a picture of that error:

[image: Console error output]

and [here's a gist with the output](https://gist.github.com/pjlamb12/a80a5edd77e46cd02449ffcbd66af6e8).

I have never seen anything about `symbol-observable` with Angular 2 until now. I installed it via `npm install` but I still got the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a little more time, and looking at the example app that John Papa used in his ng-conf 2016 presentation, I updated all the `npm` packages to the newest versions and this has gotten rid of this problem. I know longer have the `zone.js` error popping up.

If you're having issues upgrading angular 2 to rc1: upgrade all your `npm` packages as well.